# Reminder app for S40 phone

Tags: java-me, nokia, series-40

S40 doesn't allow an app to run in background. It seams the only solution is to use PushRegistry.registerAlarm.

I'm trying to make a reminder app, so when triggered it should make the phone vibrate and make noise, but unfortunately i get a small message saying "Reminder: App name" and the softkey is set to "Open". When it opens it makes the noise and vibrations (or it will, now i am just testing with a simple TextBox).

Is there a way to make the PushRegistry.registerAlarm actually open my app, not wait for yet another confirmation?

Or do you know another way to make a app run in background on S40?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually i found this article that there's no way to avoid the confirmation: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIJ000394_-_PushRegistry_confirmation_on_Series_40_MIDlets

So is there a different way to run the app in background? Afaik no, i'll get a new phone :)

Comment: For what it's worth, Windows Live Messenger on S40 has the same problem - when you receive a message the phone quietly asks whether you want to allow Messenger to run, rather than making a noise and/or vibrating.  If Microsoft haven't figured out a way around it, there probably isn't one.

Comment: Bogdan, have you found a solution to this? I'm also looking for a reminder app, could not find, decided to write one, but stumbled across this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the link given by Bogdan Piloca, there a known issue with all S40 version, from 2nd to 6th edition:

> Even if the MIDlet is signed, and the Auto-start settings are set to **Always allowed**, the prompt is presented to the user.

I guess that on S40 the PushRegistry wouldn't help you

Comment: Do other newer S40 SDKs have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIJ000394_-_PushRegistry_confirmation_on_Series_40_MIDlets) from Forum Nokia.  The page also mentioned that there is no available workaround for this situation.  Too bad for us since we are also planning to have this kind of functionality.